# get execFile stdOut on chunks

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I am trying to use execFile and log the stdOut that gives the percentage done on the task, but the callback function:

```
var child = require('child_process');

child.execFile("path/to/the/file", options, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
});
```

Waits until the process is done and then logs everything at once. 
How do i get the info while is being processed and log it in parts?, I have try this:

```
child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

But i get this error: `Cannot read property 'on' of undefined"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`.spawn()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) instead of `.exec()`/`.execFile()` for streaming the output:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var child = spawn("path/to/the/file", args);

child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

child.on('close', function(code, signal) {
  // process exited and no more data available on `stdout`/`stderr`
});
```